# placeholder not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
.txt1::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
       color:#c2c3c3;
       content:"Hey Brad,\A Tell us what's on your mind";
    }
    .txt1::-moz-input-placeholder::before {
       color:#c2c3c3;
       content:"Hey Brad,\A Tell us what's on your mind";
    }
```

Placeholder not working in Firefox ,Chrome its fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webkit uses `::-webkit-input-placeholder` to target placeholder text:

```
.txt1::-webkit-input-placeholder:before {
    color:#c2c3c3;
    content:"Hey Brad,\A Tell us what's on your mind";
}
```

While Firefox uses `:-moz-placeholder` to target the placeholder text:

```
.txt1:-moz-placeholder:before {
    color:#c2c3c3;
    content:"Hey Brad,\A Tell us what's on your mind";
}
```

You've added `input` to Firefox's selector, which isn't needed. You should only include one colon at the beginning of the selector for Firefox, not two. I would also suggest removing the extra colon after the selector `::before` and change it to `:before` as these are unnecessary. Use my code examples above and you should be good. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have questions.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-placeholder

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
.txt1::-moz-placeholder::before {
  color:#c2c3c3;
  content:"Hey Brad,\A Tell us what's on your mind";
}
```

I think there no `input` should be removed in `-moz-input-placeholder`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you add a placeholder in the `input` tag?  For example:

```
input type="" placeholder="any text"
```